# How many Kurds have been killed, injured or incarcerated by Turkey in the last 20 years?

Tags: turkey, kurdistan

Turkey has waged a conflict with Kurds over their desire for independence for a while. Is it known (ideally from sources independent of Turkish government) how many Kurds were victims of this?

By victims I mean: killed (main purpose of the question), injured (if data is available) or incarcerated  (if data is available).

Preferably with a breakdown between civilians and armed Kurdish fighters.

Comment: Its pretty abstract question I am afraid

Comment: @TalhaIrfan If it is only about deaths or imprisonments, there could be pretty good estimates from third parties.

Comment: Please provide some guidance on what 'victimized' should mean. An armed fighter being counted as a victim seems no less obvious than being denied a independent state making all of them victims.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - updated

Comment: Institutional discrimination and suppression is something difficult to derive tangible values.

Comment: @mootmoot - tangible values offer a floor to the data and an objective dataset.

Comment: The wikipedia page has various estimates. Have you read it?